# ASP.Net Calendar Control styling background behind title

Tags: asp.net, web-controls, backcolor, asp.net-webcontrol, calendar-control

I'm trying to remove grey background behind calendar title but not having any luck. This is the default calendar control found in the toolbox. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

My best guess was:

```
#Calendar1 td
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

but didn't work. I can't seem to get a handle to that background color.

[image]

Comment: That is the rendered html of the control displayed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TitleStyle-BackColor="Transparent"` property like

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" TitleStyle-BackColor="Transparent">
</asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: That worked! I thought I could use TitleStyle-CssClass and just set background-color in style block but that gave me the magenta color above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Calendar Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try setting the BorderWidth property to 0 and BackColor property to transparent.

ASP.NET Example

```
      <asp:Calendar id="calendar1" runat="server">
           <BorderWidth = "0">
           </BorderWidth>

           <TitleStyle BackColor = "Transparent">
           </TitleStyle>
      </asp:Calendar>
```